# How to enable accessibility in Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, accessibility

The [Accessibility best practices for Flex](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/flex/best_practices.html) page from Adobe website list four strategies to enable accessibility :

- Enable accessibility by default for all Flex applications
- Enable accessibility in the Adobe Flex Builder™ 3 project properties
- Enable accessibility for an individual application
- Enable accessibility using the command-line compiler

I test if the accessibility is enabled by checking the value of `Accessibility.active`, which is always false in my sample application containing only a datagrid and some buttons, using the four above strategies.

As I'm new to Flex, I don't really know where else I could search to enable it, and no,

```
Accessibility.active = true;
```

isn't a solution, as it's a read-only property ;)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FlexBuilder, go to Project->Properties->Flex Compiler and then check the *Generate accessible SWF file* checkbox.

See [this page](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/flex/components.html) for more details.

The `Accessibility.active` flag allows you to programmatically know if a user is using a screen reader. Adobe states that

> Users who view your content must have Adobe® Flash® Player 9 or later, and Internet Explorer on Windows 2000 or Windows XP or later.

Source: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=accessible_5.html

For example, we used the `Accessibility.active` flag in our application to turn off certain graphical features (a calendar based schedule builder) and turn on a more accessibile version of that feature.

Hope that helps you get on your way to creating an accessible application!

Comment: I'm now running it with Jaws and the needed script (http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/flex/jaws.html) to enable it on flex, and the `Accessibility.active` flag is now set to true. Thanks for the help

Comment: I had a lot of luck using the basic Microsoft Narrator when doing accessibility work. If you don't have a full license for Jaws and are looking for something free, that may work.